# Regex in mySQL search inside tags

Tags: php, html, mysql, regex

I have this code:

```
<h4><img class="arrow" src="/Images/page-elements/arrow-light-blue.png" 
alt="" />Day 1: Halifax</h4>
<h4><img class="arrow" src="/Images/page-elements/arrow-light-blue.png" 
alt="" />Day 2: Halifax – Pictou (2 hours)</h4>
<h4><img class="arrow" src="/Images/page-elements/arrow-light-blue.png" 
alt="" />Day 1: London</h4>
<h4><img class="arrow" src="/Images/page-elements/arrow-light-blue.png" 
alt="" />Day 2: Halifax – Victoria (2 hours)</h4>
```

I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE `meta_value` RLIKE  'Day[^>]+</h4>'
```

in MySQL, which selects everything from 'Day' to the ending `</h4>` tag.

I want it to only select stuff which has "Victoria" in it. So I want it to select only "Day 2: Halifax – Victoria (2 hours)</h4>"

How can I do this? I tried `%Victoria%` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Will there be any `<` between `Day` and `</h4>`?

Comment: No there won't be

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression like:

```
RLIKE 'Day.*Victoria'
```

Comment: Thank you. 
This works perfectly fine on (https://regexr.com/)
but it it not working on PHPmyAdmin.
When I ran `SELECT wp_postmeta.* FROM  wp_postmeta  WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value RLIKE 'Day.*Victoria.*'  `

It returned some rows which shouldn't be returned and when I copy pasted the meta_value field to  (https://regexr.com/) the website says no matches found (which is correct).

Comment: The trailing `.*` is unnecessary since `RLIKE` is not anchored at either end.

Answer (score 0):

```
RLIKE  'Victoria[^<]*/h4>'
```

Details

```
Victoria  -- look for this
[^<]*     -- match everything through the start of next tag
/h4>      -- make sure that tag is "end h4" (and include it in the match)
```

So far, this Q&A is ignoring what the OP probably wants -- namely to *extract the substring* from the text.  This is impractical in MySQL; use MySQL to find the row, then use app code to do the extraction.